# Compare two object that themself have ienumerables

Tags: c#, ienumerable, iequalitycomparer, iequatable

I have an class like this:

```
public class Inner {
    public int foo;
    public int bar;
}
```

and an outer class:

```
public class Outer {
    public string Name;
    public IEnumerable<Inner> foobars;
}
```

When I compare two objects, I do this:

```
// I have to instances of Outer, called A and B
if (A.Equals(B)) {
    // do something
}
```

I know I need to implement the IEquatable interface or possibly IEqualityComparer (or both), and while this seems simple enough, I have yet to see how to implement it in this situation where Outer has en IEnumerable of Inner objects.

Do I have to implement IEquatable/IEqualityComparer on both Inner and Outer? And how do I make sure the lists are compared properly and not just by reference?

I have searched a lot on stackoverflow and google in general but have missed the proper solution.

Comment: Have a squiz at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2009/01/15/if-you-implement-iequatablet-you-still-must-override-objects-equals-and-gethashcode/ and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 .

Comment: Looked at it and I didn't get much wiser. I know about SequenceEqual, but should I use it in the Outer IEquatable Equals method or is it used implicitly? In the Outer Equals method, can I just use `foobars.Equals(other.foobars)` or do I have to specifically use SequenceEqual in the Outer Equals method?

Comment: `should I use it in the Outer IEquatable Equals method` Yes. To be fair, you could also have just tried it yourself. :)

Comment: True. It would probably work, but I wouldn't know if this was the correct way to do it. ;-)

Comment: You need to override `Equals` in both `Outer` and `Inner` with your custom logic. This logic will including calling `SequenceEquals` on `foobars`. Don't forget to override `GetHashCode` also to not get surprising results when used in `HashSet`\`Dictionary`.

Comment: `This logic will including calling SequenceEquals on foobars` The sentence was a bit garbled. You meant that I needed to use SequenceEqual in the Outer Equals method, right?